# Ratings boxes won't line up with the rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, bootstrap-grid

I'm using bootstrap 4 to try to make a IGN inspired gaming website.  I use a script to fill out a series of rows which present the title, release date, and rating of a game in a red box in table rows.  For some bizarre reason, it doesn't quite line up, and this is what I get:

[image]

So, how do I get it to line up properly, so 9.8 is in Fallout 4 row, between the two lines, rather than being pierced by the top line?  Here is the script I use:

```
        function fillTables (){
      $.get("/api/tables", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        {
          $(".container").append("<div class = 'row'> <div class = 'col-md-10'><p style = 'font-size: 24px'>" + data[i].title + "</p>" + data[i].rel.substring(0, 10) + "</div><div class = 'col-md-2'>" + "<span class = 'mainRating'>" + data[i].rating + "</span></div></div>");
    }
```

And here is my style tag:

```
    <style>

.row
{
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-width: 2px;
}

.mainRating
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:red;

}

.container
{
    width: 80%;
    /*adjust this based on screen size.  Big screens its 70%, medium screens its 80%, small screens its 100%*/
}

.card
{
    width: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s because those `<span>`s are inline elements. Try turning them into `<div>`s or adding to your CSS:

```css
.mainRating {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that messes up the dimensions on my boxes :(

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re trying to accomplish here then. The size of the box is coming from the padding content and the padding. You could reduce the padding as well.

Comment: If you want the whole box to be red, with the text at the top you can add a class to the `col-md-2` that sets the background to red, and then remove the `background: red` from `.mainRating`